# How to Extract Value From Response Header with 302 Status Code?

Tags: regex, jmeter, response-headers

I've been trying to extract value from a response header. I tried using RegEx and Boundary Extractor but I coudln't make it. And that request always gives a **302** response code.

My Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
server: nginx
date: Wed, 23 Feb 2022 12:35:19 GMT
content-length: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
location: https://somedomainname.com/tr/checkout/orderConfirmation/2202231535500
content-language: tr
connection: close
```

What I want to extract is order confirmation number: 2202231535500 , which will be coming as a dynamic value during testing.

Comment: From having a glance at the [docs](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), regular expressions should fit your needs. What expressions have you tried?

Comment: Please post your regex here...

Comment: I tried orderConfirmation/:(.+) with $1$ template

Comment: @GökhanUçar You have an extra colon `:` which wouldn't allow for a match. Try this: `orderConfirmation/(\d+)` (it will only take numbers after the static string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
orderConfirmation/([0-9]+)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/SMFhx4/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  orderConfirmation/       'orderConfirmation/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```